# Include LAMP PHP path

Tags: linux, lamp

I am currently using LAMP package . I can run php from terminal using `lampfolder/php/bin ./php filename` . But Now i want to use the php file without going into lamp folder .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export PATH="path"
```

Include this in .profile